# How to find file property that is showing google drive synced tick mark

Tags: windows, command-line, server, file-properties, flysystem-google-drive

I am using google drive sync app. Once the file is synced from pc to drive , its file icon is show tick mark that means it is completed.

I want to run a scheduled task everyday that delete all files that is already synced to google drive. For that , I think I need to check this file property.

I tried command line to get property of synced file but nothing I found in there

Comment: Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Why don't you let Windows manage physical disk space instead? It will purge local copies of cloud-synced files, when disk space pressure increases.

Comment: @IInspectable, thansk for the suggestion, How to set purge only cloud synced file.

Comment: Only local files that are backed by cloud storage are candidates for deletion.